# How to convert word documents to swf viewer programmatically

Tags: c#, ms-word, flash

well I need a method to convert word files to swf.
please don't suggest scribd.com or any other similar tools because I need to host the files at my server.
so is this possible?
I know that you can convert pdf to swf using [link text](http://www.swftools.org)
but I didn't find anything about word documents

Comment: Why don't you just convert the word docs to pdf first then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

**Adobe FlashPaper**
Or **Print2Flash**

Both tools provide facility to convert any printable document to swf, there is also facility to convert document programetically.

Comment: I guess these are both windows applications that cannot be used programmatically?

Comment: Print2Flash have a version for 500$ which can used on a server.
http://print2flash.com/register/

Comment: Print2Flash is as simple as running a command line
p2fserver.exe c:\1.docx c:\1.swf
to convert document, i have already created service for convertion process, request initiated by asp.net page.

You can use free edition to convert document as well, but it will show it's logo in converted document, i prefer "Pro mode" which is around 80$.

problem with FlashPaper is adobe has stopped it's support.

Answer (score 1):

PDFs and PowerPoint files can be displayed as SWF directly, without any conversion on your side, using [Google Docs Viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer). The files can be hosted on your server, must be accessible through a public URL though... [This article](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html) explains how you can easily embed the viewer to display a file from a given URL.

As klausbyskov wrote, you could convert the word files to PDFs and then use Google Docs Viewer to display the PDFs. Converting word files requires word to be installed on the server! [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607669/how-do-i-convert-word-files-to-pdf-programmatically) explains how you can convert word files to PDFs from .Net.

Answer (score 1):

The [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/) DMS uses [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/) to convert Word to PDF and then [PDF2SWF](http://www.swftools.org/) to convert PDF to Flash.

**(edit)** The conversion process is managed by http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter