# view documents in browser without downloading

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, documentviewer

I have an asp.net site which is essentially a repository of documents uploaded by users.

I would like visitors to the site to be able to view any of these documents in some sort of "document viewer" without ever being able to download the file to their local system.

Documents are all Office files and PDFs.

Please advise if there are open source or commercial "document viewer" controls that you have used and would recommend.

EDIT: I own the server and can load any server components. Unfortunately i can't use flash based viewers as it must be compatible accross all browsers and devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just answering for anyone else looking up this info.

I ended up going with Adeptol's Ajax Document Viewer which works really well.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar requirement and we converted all office docs and PDF files to SWF files using Print2Flash (http://print2flash.com/) and display them in the browser. There are both free and commercial editions of print2flash.

Comment: related SO question for doc to swf - [c# - how to convert word documents to swf viewer programaticaly - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969113/how-to-convert-word-documents-to-swf-viewer-programaticaly)