# converting doc to html and pdf

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, pdf, ms-word

How can we convert a doc file into an html and a pdf file using c# in a web application?

I am making a web application and i want to convert a doc file into html and pdf as soon as the user clicks on the desired button

Comment: I found an answer to this and it works perfectly

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607669/how-do-i-convert-word-files-to-pdf-programmatically?s=31dc0f5d-5059-47e5-a0d3-339b39ff94a0#new-answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a word doc to pure html, you will need to run a function that strips all of the garbage characters from your word document.. you would be recreating your own basic CMS.

If you want to convert a word doc to PDF, you will need to run Microsoft Office on a Microsoft server and it gets quite complex and expensive to buy licences for using Office on the server.

If you want to simply upload a word doc to a server, you can display it online using Google Doc Viewer without any conversion. [Here is an short article](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html) on how to embed a document on a website. All that is required is a short amount of code:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: i don't want to embed the document.
i want to actually convert it on the fly

as soon as the user clicks on html button- an html version of the doc file opens, as soon as user clicks on pdf button- a pdf version of the doc file opens

if i save it as save as psf using the word doc and save it in the folder i can open the file using Process.Start("file path")

but i don't want to save the file
i want to create a new one everytime on runtime

Comment: could u help me with it?
i am new to all this
i have no idea how to proceed

Comment: i have not done it before because it is very complex and gets expensive.