# Word document (.doc & .docx) to pdf conversion using C# in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am looking for an easy way to convert doc and docx extension files to pdf using C# and ASP.NET. I had previously used iTextSharp for the purpose but that requires creating a document from the scratch. But I want a way to convert the Word files as it is to pdf. Like if it includes images, tables etc they must be converted to pdf as it is. Is there any free library or code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607669/how-do-i-convert-word-files-to-pdf-programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can check this [PDFConverter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/), it might helpful to you. It is a COM  component, callable from .NET.
2) Or you can check this open source library [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php).

3) And the third option is [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/Products/Aspose.Pdf/Default.aspx) libraray

Comment: Aspose has more recommendations than others. but still you can check the views and recommendations on web

Comment: Where did you find PDFSharp can do such conversion?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to buy a component then you can use [Aspose Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx), which is best for converting Word document to PDF as it is. There is no need to install Ms Office if this component is used.