# Conversion of Word document to EPUB

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, epub

I require to convert .doc or .docx files (Microsoft Word Document) into .epub formats. I don't want to use Spire.Doc DLL. Please suggest some measures. Can it be done through DotNetZip library?

Comment: Just out of morbid curiosity, why not use Spire.Doc?  Is there something about it you don't like?  Knowing this might be able to help readers to suggest a 'better' alternative.

Comment: @Jeremy Because Spire.Doc is available as a trial version only and i require a permanent solution for this.

Comment: Ah, so you need a free library.  Unfortunately, and I'm almost positive, there isn't one other than Spire.doc with the capability of integrating in your project.  Also, DotNetZip will not help in this case.

Comment: @Jeremy Can you suggest any other means for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked into this a little bit and unfortunately I don't see many alternatives.  If you want to do it on the cheap, then you could try this:

Note: This ultimately requires you to convert it to epub yourself.  The good news, though, is that it IS an open standard and that some people have done this already and code is free on the net. See [EPUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB) on wikipedia for the specifics on the open format.

1. Convert your document to pdf
2. Convert the pdf to epub

*Why have I chosen this method?*

I have not found any examples of doc-to-epub, but I wanted to go the fastest route with minimal expense using these examples:

Eric Ness has provided a fantastic example of how to convert a Word document to pdf on stackoverflow:  [How do I convert Word files to PDF programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607669/how-do-i-convert-word-files-to-pdf-programmatically)

André van heerwaarde has posted a project on codeproject: [Conversion of PDF to EPUB Format](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44395/Conversion-of-PDF-to-EPUB-Format) which is downloadable and open source.  You can garner whatever you require from his code.

Hope this helps!