# Using Outlook Office.Interop from a C# windows service

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I  just created a C# Desktop application for my personal use which reads my outlook calendar using  `Office.Interop`  libraries and posts all items to the Google calendar. It worked fine until I tried to convert it to a windows service. It always throws following error:

```
The file E:\...\Outlook Data File.pst cannot be opened.
```

I tried with different user accounts, but nothing worked. At the same time, the desktop application works as expected. Any idea?

Code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application application = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace applicationNamespace = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder folder = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items calendarItems = null;

application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
applicationNamespace = application.GetNamespace("MAPI"); ;
folder = applicationNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
calendarItems = folder.Items;

foreach (
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem item in calendarItems)
{
    // process item
}
```

Comment: Permissions on the file? Are you running the service as yourself or local system etc?

Comment: Can you show the code you're using?

Comment: @PaulFarry: I run the service as my current account, which is an administrator. Code attached. Thanks.

Comment: Stab in the dark, but are you running the service while Outlook is open?  I've only used Outlook interop with Exchange accounts, but I know Excel likes to lock files so other process can't use them.

Comment: I tried both outlook running/not running scenarios, but that too didn't help. thanks for the comments. (BTW, I couldn't login to my account due to some unknown reasons hence this comment is a bit late)

Comment: We are facing the same issue using Office Interop within TFS 2013 in "non-interactive" mode. Something really funny happens if we leave Word Application open, the interop works perfectly, if we leave it closed, it randomly fails ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Interop is not supported in an unattended, non-interactive application:

Related Stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13480267/1716736 
MS article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757