# How to convert byte array of word doc into byte array of pdf

Tags: c#, sql, pdf

I have word document in Sql Server database, I need to read it and convert to PDF file.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) ?

Comment: What problems are you facing off? How to get data from sql server, how to read it or how to convert? Don't offense on minuses you get just explain what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I usually hate just posting links to answers, but since this answer is still longer than your question, I'll make an exception:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/608153/131809