# Convert word to pdf in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-applications, pdf-generation, ms-office

There are word documents in physical path on server.
Now, I just need to read them and download to the client machine by converting them to PDF format.

My program is in VB.Net

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert Word files to PDF programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607669/how-do-i-convert-word-files-to-pdf-programmatically)

Answer (score 2):

We do the same things and we use [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/). It's a free program and once installed, it creates a virtual printer called "PDFCreator". All you do then is print the relevant document to that printer. PDFCreator lets you set where you want the files to be saved. Or you can do this using a FileDialog from within VB. Hope this helps