# Using OpenXML to save a PowerPoint presentation as a PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk

My objective is to make an automated server-side process to turn a `.ppt` into a `.pdf`. Microsoft themselves suggested that I use OpenXML, and now I'm looking at that.

My question is:

**Can I actually achieve my objective using OpenXML?**

I'm having a hard time finding the methods that I'd expect, such as "save as" [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.presentation.presentation_members.aspx)

Or perhaps I'm just misunderstanding how it all works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *... to turn a .ppt into a .pdf. Microsoft themselves suggested that I use OpenXML ... Can I actually achieve my objective using OpenXML?*

For the conversion of a `.ppt` into `.pdf`? I'm curious to see where you have read this ;-)

**No** It's just impossible using OpenXml SDK:

- OpenXml SDK permits to create, modify **OpenXml** documents (`.pptx` in case of PowerPoint) and here you are talking about `.ppt` (Biff format)
- There is **NO** method for converting as **PDF**. OpenXml SDK permits to retrieve, create, modify the content of the document Without an Office Application but DOES NOT contain any methods to render it, or such Office Application methods such as `SaveAs()` ...

---

No, a common way to convert Office documents as pdf is to use `Office.Interop`.

This thread [How do I convert Word files to PDF programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607669/how-do-i-convert-word-files-to-pdf-programmatically) is related to Word but it can help you, it's the same with PowerPoint.