# Using Office.Interop, certain Powerpoint filenames won't convert

Tags: c#, .net, path, powerpoint, office-interop

I have a program that converts `.ppt` or `pptx`  files to `png`'s using `C#` and the `Microsoft.Office.Interop` stuff.

It works most of the time, but under certain circumstances, it seems to fail on specific filenames for some nondescript reason.

`HRESULT E_FAIL at ... Presentations.Open`

It'll fail on  `CT_Stress_Test - Copy (16).pptx` and `CT_Stress_Test - Copy (11).pptx` It works for `(2)` thru `(19)`, but fails on only these two. My question is why?

If I were to make copies of these copies, or rename them to something else, it'll convert just fine, so I think it might have something to do with the filename.

I have the same conversion program running on my server and my local machine. My local machine (Win 7) converts the problem files just file. It's only on the server (Win 2008) that I have problems with these two filenames.

**EDIT**: I've found another number that doesn't work: `(38)`

**EDIT**: I formatted the strings with `Path` functions, and that didn't help.

**EDIT**: I was able to fix it by trimming all the spaces from the file names. I still want to know why this happens, though.

Here's the program:

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Timers;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;


namespace converter
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int threadLimit=0;
        public static string inDir;
        public static string outDir;
        public static string procDir;
        public static Thread[] converterThreads;
        public static BlockingCollection<string> todo;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            todo = new BlockingCollection<string>();
            inDir = args[0];
            outDir = args[1]+"\\";
            procDir = args[2]+"\\";
            Int32.TryParse(args[3],out threadLimit);
            converterThreads = new Thread[threadLimit];

            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(inDir); //Watcher "thread"
            watcher.Filter = "*.ppt*";
            watcher.NotifyFilter = watcher.NotifyFilter | NotifyFilters.CreationTime;
            watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(fileChanged); 
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;


            //Create consumer threads
            for(var i=0;i<threadLimit;i++)
            {
                Conversion con = new Conversion();
                converterThreads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(con.watchCollection));
                converterThreads[i].Start();
            }


            //stay open
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        //Producer
        private static void fileChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            if(!(e.FullPath.Contains("~$"))){ //Ignore temp files
                Console.WriteLine("found =" + e.FullPath);
                todo.Add(e.FullPath);
            }
        }
    }



    class Logger{

        static void toLog(String msg)    
        {
                //TODO: log file    
        }

    }




    //Consumer
    class Conversion
    {
        String input;
        String output;
        String outDir;
        String process;
        String nameWith;
        String nameWithout;
        string dir;
        static List<CorruptFile> cFiles = new List<CorruptFile>();
        int retryLimit = 20;

        public Conversion()
        {
            this.outDir = Program.outDir;
            this.process = Program.procDir;
        }

        //Continually watches collection for files to take.
        public void watchCollection()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                try
                {
                    dir = Program.todo.Take();
                    if (dir != null)
                    {
                        this.nameWithout = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dir);
                        this.nameWith = Path.GetFileName(dir);
                        this.output = Path.GetDirectoryName(dir) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dir);
                        Console.WriteLine("output = " + this.output);
                        this.input = Path.GetFullPath(dir);
                        Console.WriteLine("thread took " + this.nameWith);
                        convertPpt();
                    }
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException) { }
            }
        }

        public void convertPpt()
        {
            try
            {
                var app = new PowerPoint.Application();
                var pres = app.Presentations;
                var file = pres.Open(input, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
                file.SaveAs(output, Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsPNG, MsoTriState.msoTrue);
                file.Close();
                app.Quit();
                Console.WriteLine("file converted " + input);
                moveFile();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("convertPpt failed " + e);
                try
                {
                    foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("POWERPNT"))
                    {
                        proc.Kill();
                        Console.WriteLine("process killed");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e3)
                {
                }

                try
                {
                    if (!(cFiles.Any(x => x.fileName == dir)))
                    {
                        cFiles.Add(new CorruptFile(dir));
                        Console.WriteLine("file added to watch list");
                        Program.todo.Add(dir);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var found = cFiles.Find(x => x.fileName == dir);
                        Console.WriteLine("in watch list = " + found.fileName);
                        if (found.numRetry >= retryLimit)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(nameWith+ " to be ignored");
                            try
                            {
                                cFiles.Remove(found);
                                Console.WriteLine("File ignored");
                                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
                                Console.WriteLine("Moving: " + input);
                                if (File.Exists("C:\\corrupt\\" + nameWith))
                                {
                                    File.Replace(input, "C:\\corrupt\\" + nameWith, null);
                                    Console.WriteLine("file moved to C:\\corrupt\\");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    File.Move(input, "C:\\corrupt\\" + nameWith);
                                    Console.WriteLine("file moved to C:\\corrupt\\");
                                }
                            }
                            catch(Exception e5)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("could not move file " + e5);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("retrying file on watch list");
                            found.numRetry++;
                            Program.todo.Add(dir);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch { }


            }

            moveDir();
        }
        public void moveFile()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("moving" + input);
            try
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("moving {0} to {1}", input, process + nameWith));
                if (File.Exists(process + nameWith))
                {
                    File.Replace(input, process + nameWith, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    File.Move(input, process + nameWith);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Unable to move the file {0} ", input) + e);
                try
                {
                    foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("POWERPNT"))
                    {
                        proc.Kill();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e3)
                {
                }
            }
        }

        public void moveDir()
        {
            if(!Directory.Exists(output)){
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("moving dir " + output);
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("moving dir {0} to {1} ", output, outDir + nameWithout));

                if (Directory.Exists(outDir + nameWithout))
                {
                    Directory.Delete(outDir + nameWithout, true);
                }
                if (Directory.Exists(output))
                {
                    Directory.Move(output, outDir + nameWithout);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Unable to move the directory {0} ", output) + e);
                try
                {
                    foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("POWERPNT"))
                    {
                        proc.Kill();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e3)
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class CorruptFile{
        public string fileName;
        public int numRetry;

       public CorruptFile(string fn){
            fileName = fn;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up is a warning from Microsoft in [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757) here. Money quote is:

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support,
>   Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended,
>   non-interactive client application or component (including ASP,
>   ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable
>   behaviour and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

Next question is why not use OpenXML for this? Here's a simple sample to get you started which counts the number of slides in a deck.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Packaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;

namespace OpenXmlDemo
{
    class PptOpenXmlDemo
    {
        public int PptGetSlideCount(string fileName)
        {
            //  Return the number of slides in a PowerPoint document.
            const string documentRelationshipType = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument";
            const string presentationmlNamespace = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main";

            int returnValue = 0;

            using (Package pptPackage = Package.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                //  Get the main document part (presentation.xml).
                foreach (System.IO.Packaging.PackageRelationship relationship in pptPackage.GetRelationshipsByType(documentRelationshipType))
                {
                    //  There should be only a single relationship that refers to the document.
                    Uri documentUri = PackUriHelper.ResolvePartUri(new Uri("/", UriKind.Relative), relationship.TargetUri);
                    PackagePart documentPart = pptPackage.GetPart(documentUri);

                    //  Get the slide part from the package.
                    if (documentPart != null)
                    {
                        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                        doc.Load(documentPart.GetStream());

                        //  Manage namespaces to perform XPath queries.
                        XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
                        nsManager.AddNamespace("p", presentationmlNamespace);

                        //  Retrieve the list of slide references from the document.
                        XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//p:sldId", nsManager);
                        if (nodes != null)
                        {
                            returnValue = nodes.Count;
                        }
                    }
                    //  There is only one officeDocument part. Get out of the loop now.
                    break;
                }
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726228/using-openxml-to-save-a-powerpoint-presentation-as-a-pdf) is why I'm not using OpenXML.

Comment: Because you may have PPTX _and_ PPT files? Fair enough I suppose. How about a 3rd party component? From memory Aspose have a fairly comprehensive range.

Comment: Not just because I have PPT files, but also because, as he said "There is NO method for converting as PDF. OpenXml... DOES NOT contain... methods such as `SaveAs()`". I turned down Aspose because their online demo showing conversion wasn't working for me.

Comment: @Houseman Another company that I've used with some success is Independentsoft. They also have a specific Presentation component. While I haven't bought this component from them I do use other components by them and am impressed with their level of support.