# How to take word file in memory stream, store it in buffer and return as PDF?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext, office-interop

I searched a lot [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/808119/How-to-convert-word-to-pdf-using-Csharp-Net), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607669/how-do-i-convert-word-files-to-pdf-programmatically), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607669/how-do-i-convert-word-files-to-pdf-programmatically)  about how can I convert a word file to pdf in C# but it seems all the ways :

1)itextsharp -- needs license(cannot afford)

2)Interop.Word -- need to have Office\word installed to be able to use it(cannot do so)

3)winnovative wordtopdf -- needs license(cannot afford)

4)evopdf.word to pdf -- same as winnovative wordtopdf(cannot afford)
5) online api's -- security breach

I am thinking is to get data in Filestream and manipulate it as word file as below:

```
 HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(FilePath);
                response.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");                
                return new FileContentResult(response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result, "application/pdf");
```

Ofcourse this code won't work but may I know what extra parameters do I add or how does a word to pdf converter actually works ? Or maybe convert word file to OpenXMl(read it written somewhere) and then convert to PDf ? Thanks in advance.

btw all this is done inside a MVC controller .

Edit1. Please mind that I've already mentioned than I cannot use Interop. So it is not what I want as answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert Word files to PDF programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607669/how-do-i-convert-word-files-to-pdf-programmatically)

Comment: But that solution is not the solution for me.They use interop which I already mentioned is not what I want.

Comment: If you have on-prem SharePoint use the Word Automation Services to perform the conversion.

Comment: @ShaliniRaj did you even read all the answers in that question? or you just read the top anwer, then close it?

Comment: @Mark i did read all of them. seems like i can use spire.doc (has 3 page limit) or Sautinsoft Uoffice. btw could plz check [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Convert-DOC-DOCX-file-to-5c32bc0a#content) and tell as to why the line u.InitWord() is not working(it is never equal to zero). I tried to remove the if condition but the line  u.ConvertFile(inFile, outFile, SautinSoft.UseOffice.eDirection.DOCX_to_PDF); return int . how can I use that to make a pdf file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenXML is sadly not a complete option as it does not include a rendering engine to convert the Word document to a PDF file - it only contains the SDK to read and interpret the OpenXML file format. (See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18728669/9552003)

Your code would require a rendering stage after the reading in the file. PDF is a great file format but can be notoriously difficult to handle, which is why Interop or external libraries are recommended. If Interop is not a viable solution for you, you may well have to defer to an external resource such as iText in order to achieve what you want.

Comment: how do I go for word to pdf in iText. I saw there is by no means we can get a pdf file from word file.

Comment: Having not used iText, I couldn't say. It does look like there are equivalent libraries if you do a search, so it'd be a matter of taking your pick.

Comment: @ShaliniRaj [This will probably be the easiest way to convert from word to pdf.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.exportasfixedformat.aspx) I've used it in my own projects and there's the benefit of being able to use it free of restrictions even in commercial applications.

Comment: @emsimpson92 thank you but i already mentioned that i cannot use interop.

Comment: @emsimpson92      seems like i can use spire.doc (has 3 page limit) or Sautinsoft Uoffice. btw could plz check this and tell as to why the line u.InitWord() is not working(it is never equal to zero). I tried to remove the if condition but the line u.ConvertFile(inFile, outFile, SautinSoft.UseOffice.eDirection.DOCX_to_PDF); return int . how can I use that to make a pdf file ?

Comment: I would recommend PDFSharp for pdf modification in C#. It is 100% free, even for commercial use, so you won't run into page limits or anything like that. That's what I've used when interop isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you want me to debug `u.InitWord()` for you, you'll need to provide a code sample so I can see what's going on.