# Convert text file to PDF file using Powershell

Tags: .net, pdf, powershell, file-conversion

I have a text file that has simple firmware versions on it. I need to convert the text file to a secure pdf file using powershell scripts.

Also, Is there a way to put a date and timestamp on the file when its converted?

I don't quite know how to do it I'm fairly new using powershell, thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific about the text file? And does the computer that will be running the script has Word 2010/2013 installed?

Comment: My machine has Word 2007 installed. It needs to run on almost all machines though, and I cant assume they have word installed. Is that the only way? The Text file has just text separated by endlines, more specifically just the part and the firmware number and so on.I could possibly do it in c# but after some research it seems I cant do it nativley without another library

Comment: I think it is possible to do it in PowerShell/C# with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word. Word is not the only way in my opinion but you'll need third party library/software. Also this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607669/how-do-i-convert-word-files-to-pdf-programmatically) might help.

Comment: Powershell does not inherently have the ability to convert to or from PDF. You will need to either package your script with libraries to perform the conversion, or need to be able to assume that they will have Word or some other application installed that will perform the conversion for you.

Answer (score 3):

I got this to work with Word 2010, but it should work with 2007 as well:

```
# File paths
$txtPath = "C:\Users\Public\test.txt"
$pdfPath = "C:\Users\Public\test.pdf"

# Required Word Variables
$wdExportFormatPDF = 17
$wdDoNotSaveChanges = 0

# Create a hidden Word window
$word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$word.visible = $false

# Add a Word document
$doc = $word.documents.add()

# Put the text into the Word document
$txt = Get-Content $txtPath
$selection = $word.selection
$selection.typeText($txt)

# Set the page orientation to landscape
$doc.PageSetup.Orientation = 1

# Export the PDF file and close without saving a Word document
$doc.ExportAsFixedFormat($pdfPath,$wdExportFormatPDF)
$doc.close([ref]$wdDoNotSaveChanges)
$word.Quit()
```

Comment: Does the pdf in this case need to be created before we run the script?

Comment: You don't need to pre-create the PDF.

Comment: @TimFerrill hope this can still get answered now, but is there any way that I can do this and make the PDF page landscape, rather than portrait?

Comment: @chrisdoubleu13 Sure thing. Added a line to handle the page orientation.

Comment: @TimFerrill Is there a way to keep the formatting of the content of the txt file, for example the line breaks?

Comment: @StackJack I think adding -Raw to the Get-Content line will do it:
$txt = Get-Content $txtPath -Raw

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to having to assume that the user has Word or some other such application installed would be to include a library with your script that will support converting text to PDF. iTextSharp was specifically designed to work with .Net to create and maintain PDF documents. You can get it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/).

The only stipulation is that it is licensed software using the AGPL (free!) license structure unless you plan on packing this within your own software or some such and don't plan on having it be open source. It sounds like you're just writing a script, that should not be a problem. If you [go find a v4 copy](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp-LGPL/4.1.6) of iTextSharp you can actually get away without having to disclose everything as open source, so you may want to go that route.

Good reference for using it with powershell is [slipsec.com/blog post 414](http://slipsec.com/blog/?p=414), which is where I usually reference to borrow code when I have to use the library myself (twice, but I think it's tedious and annoying so I don't use it often, but then again I rarely need to generate PDF documents in bulk or in an automated fashion).

So, the nitty gritty... This loads the DLL, creates the objects needed to generate the PDF file (it's using the font Ariel, at a font size of 10).

Then it reads the source file (C:\temp\source.txt is used as an example), and adds the content to the `$paragraph` object, adding a New Line character for each line, otherwise is smashes all of the text into one big ugly clump.

Then it opens the file object (effectively creating the file), adds the `$paragraph` object to the file, and closes the file. No save is needed, adding the `$paragraph` object writes the data directly to the drive.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\path\to\itextsharp\itextsharp.dll")

$doc = New-Object iTextSharp.text.Document
$fileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream("C:\temp\output.pdf", [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
[iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter]::GetInstance($doc, $filestream)

#iTextSharp provides a class to work with fonts, but first we have to register them:
[iTextSharp.text.FontFactory]::RegisterDirectories()
$arial = [iTextSharp.text.FontFactory]::GetFont("arial", 10)

$paragraph = New-Object iTextSharp.text.Paragraph

$paragraph.add((gc C:\temp\source.txt|%{"$_`n"})) | Out-Null
$doc.open()
$doc.add($paragraph) | Out-Null
$doc.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using CMD you can do it in one line, clearly for multiple lines of data it will needs be more elaborate. So you could simplest shell a batch file to do something along the lines of.

```
(echo %Date% & echo/ & echo Hello World!)>temp.txt & write /pt "%cd%\temp.txt" "Microsoft Print to PDF" "Microsoft Print to PDF" "%cd%\temp.pdf" &temp.pdf
```

[image]