# How i can save a log with powershell in format pdf?

Tags: powershell

Actually i make one test unit that print this result:

```
info: serving app on http://127.0.0.1:4000

  Usuario
superagent: Enable experimental feature http2
    ✓ realiza um registro de usuário (511ms)
    ✓ realiza login com o usuário registrado (142ms)
    ✓ realiza login com dados incorretos (145ms)

   PASSED 

  total       : 3
  passed      : 3
  time        : 2s
```

If i try to export this log in format .txt i have several problems with special characters and accents, as you can see:

```
adonis test > yourfile.txt
```

When i open the "yourfile.txt":

```
[32minfo[39m: serving app on http://127.0.0.1:4000

  Usuario
    Ô£ô realiza um registro de usu├írio (456ms)
    Ô£ô realiza login com o usu├írio registrado (135ms)
    Ô£ô realiza login com dados incorretos (126ms)

   PASSED 

  total       : 3
  passed      : 3
  time        : 1s
```

I'm thinking if there's a way to export this log in pdf to workaround this problem or if there's a way to show the special characters/accents correctly.

if i do a `adonis test > yourfile.pdf` the pdf generated is broken.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basic Powershell - batch convert Word Docx to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534292/basic-powershell-batch-convert-word-docx-to-pdf)

Comment: @Matthew thanks but this question is about to convert docx -> pdf, in my case is txt -> pdf, if i try to save using .docx i have the same problem (archive is broken)

Comment: Instead of redirecting with `>`, assign into a variable and use [Add-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content?view=powershell-6)?

Comment: If not that, perhaps this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892631/convert-text-file-to-pdf-file-using-powershell

Answer (score 2):

This may have to do with OutputEncoding.
Try:

```
$enc = [Console]::OutputEncoding
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [text.encoding]::utf8

adonis test | Out-File yourfile.txt -Encoding utf8 -Force

[Console]::OutputEncoding = $enc
```