# How to convert byte array of word doc into byte array of pdf document in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, stream, crystal-reports-2010

I have a sequence of bytes as follows (Word format) exported from crystal report

```
 Stream stream = cryRpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.WordForWindows);
```

I would like to convert that stream to a PDF stream to be stored in a varbinary column in sql server database.

There is a barcode in the document and i am unable to embed it when I export to pdf. Exporting to word works though so I want to try from Word to PDF
Can anyone assist me in getting this PDF byte[]?

Comment: Are you looking for: [How do I convert Word files to PDF programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607669/how-do-i-convert-word-files-to-pdf-programmatically/608153)

Comment: Hi Corak, No I want to do this programatically, convert a word byte [] to a pdf byte[]

Comment: You have to convert the Word-Document to a PDF-Document (using some high level library), then you may read the Bytes of this PDF-Document/File.

Comment: @CoDeGiRl, you could accomplish that by writing the byte[] to a file and using the answer to the question Corak linked to.  It's nontrivial (to put it lightly) to convert a Word document to a PDF document without involving Word itself.

Comment: DrKotch, when you say "You have to convert the Word-Document to a PDF-Document" do you mean a physical pdf file on disk?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using  the [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word/). Once you added it on your application you can flush your Byte Array to a temporary file, then open the temp file with **Interop.Word**, work with it, save the result and read the result back into a Byte Array.

Here's a sample code snippet that does just that:

```
// byte[] fileBytes = getFileBytesFromDB();
var tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
File.WriteAllBytes(tmpFile, fileBytes);

Application app = new word.Application();
Document doc = app.Documents.Open(filePath);

// Save DOCX into a PDF
var pdfPath = "path-to-pdf-file.pdf";
doc.SaveAs2(pdfPath, word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);

doc.Close();
app.Quit(); // VERY IMPORTANT: do this to close the MS Word instance
byte[] pdfFileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(pdfPath);
File.Delete(tmpFile);
```

For more info regarding the topic you can also [read this post](http://www.ryadel.com/en/open-edit-word-doc-docx-file-byte-array-c-msword-interop/) on my blog.