# Converting a docx word file into pdf without MS Word on the system

Tags: c#, pdf, ms-word

Is there a way of converting a word docx file to pdf without having MS word on the system. Our infrastructure team doesnt want to install MS Word/Open office on the server because of security reasons.

I have tried using docx.codeplex.com to manipulate the content of word file which docx.codeplex handles perfectly.

Any thoughts/experiences are much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert Word files to PDF programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607669/how-do-i-convert-word-files-to-pdf-programmatically)

Comment: Its not a duplicate. The link you mentioned is using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word assembly which requires word to be installed on the system to work

Comment: There's more that one answer there giving you MANY other options.

Comment: I do it with a DevExpress DocumentServer. (these are commercial libraries)

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use [doc4j.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/docx4j.NET/) port of java library.
[Here's](http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2014/09/docx-to-pdf-in-c-net/) a walkthrough for that