# Convert TMP to PDF

Tags: .net, vb.net, pdf

I have no sample code to post as I do not even think this is possible. I have a third-party program that creates .TMP files. I then manually go in and open those files in word, then save as PDF. It is very time consuming.

I am hoping some sort of function could be written to convert all .TMP files in a specified folder to .PDF -- The filename can stay the same.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Even pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Take a look at iTextSharp. http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Comment: Can you read those files, poss as plain text? If so, then yes. Get a `PDF` sdk like `iTextSharp` or `SharpPDF`.

Comment: You can write a DOS batch file that can automate this. You will have to write a Word Automation program that opens the program and saves the files as PDF. You can call the program in the batch file. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607669/how-do-i-convert-word-files-to-pdf-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a print-to-PDF utility to convert your .TMP files to PDF. There are numerous ones out there (*e.g.* if you have Adobe Acrobat installed, you should find an Adobe PDF "printer" already installed). The system sees it as a print driver, showing up in your list of available printers, but when a print job is sent to its queue, it prompts for a filename and writes the output in PDF form.