# Why my report's layout disturbs when exported to PDF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, rdlc, reportviewer

I am using report viewer to display my rdlc report in CHROME with asp.net 4.0 but problem is that the layout disturbs when it export it to PDF but remains good if I export to WORD. Why ?

I am trying to FIX it with PDF but can't find anyway. How to make it correct ?

Comment: There's no real magic way of making it better or the same, as there are a number of factors that can affect it.  PDF and Word export are completely different rendering targets with different code making the translations.  In most cases like this, the simpler the layout of your report, the more luck you'll have with getting the PDF renderer and Word renderer to look nearly the same.

Comment: ok lets say that i don't want same but i want to have the PDF in propr layout,

Comment: You'll have to figure that out with trial and error.  I've found the PDF renderer in RDLC to be a little flaky in the past.  Another thing for you to try is to render to Word, since that seems to be working the best for you, then use a Word to PDF converter on that to get your PDF.  There are a number of converters out there that might do a better job of converting a Word doc than RDLC does creating a PDF.  Here's a link to help you with that:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607669/how-do-i-convert-word-files-to-pdf-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

I assume "layout disturbs" means objects are not being placed where you expect them in the PDF but in Word it looks ok.

I've seen things like this happen when you have overlapping controls or autofit/autogrowth width/height.

- Try designing your report with space between your controls.
- Ensure controls are not overlapping
- Make your controls fixed width and do not allow them to grow
- Combine overlapping controls into one control as an expression

If this doesn't fix your issue please provide more information and screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Dear All this my first attempt in stack overflow

Please check your margin properties left and right
and reduce it as much as possible

Comment: this is more a comment than an answer