# Converting docx document from a MemoryStream to a PDF using ABCpdf.Net in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, abcpdf, novacode-docx

I'm using Novacode DocX to take some data and convert this to a docx document. This is then put into a memory stream. Now, I want to take this memorystream, using ABCpdf.NET, and convert it to a PDF document. Is this possible? I can't figure out whether this is possible using the ABCpdf.Net.

I've tried simple this just to get it out like this:

```
var doc = new Doc();
doc.Read(docxMemoryStream);
```

This would just read the stream into the document. But I can't figure out if I can take this, now document, and convert it into pdf?

This in the end have to be deployed on a CRM server that we cannot control, regarding what to install. So having Word installed is out of the question, which removes the Interop function sadly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert Word files to PDF programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607669/how-do-i-convert-word-files-to-pdf-programmatically)

Comment: Might be missing some information, because I wouldn't say it's a duplicate. (I've read that post several times in my search)