# Save a DocX with DocumentFormat.OpenXml

Tags: c#, docx

I should create a `PDF` file from a `Word` document in `C#`. I'm using `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` for creating or reading a document like

```
// create a new docx
using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Create(
            "test.docx", WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
{
    document.AddMainDocumentPart();
    document.MainDocumentPart.Document = new Document(
                new Body(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("some text")))));
}
```

In this document I must add an image and then create a `PDF`. I can't find a way to create it. Do you have any advice? Thanks

Comment: *PDF* has nothing to do with Word, docx or the Open Office XML format. Essentially you are asking "How can I create a PDF file in C#"? Search for a library that creates PDF documents, eg iText. There are a lot of similar questions.

Comment: MigraDoc and PdfSharp are also pretty good for making PDFs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert Word files to PDF programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607669/how-do-i-convert-word-files-to-pdf-programmatically)