# Acumatica: file types conversion to pdf

Tags: c#, acumatica

How in Acumatica convert different file types to pdf(Excel, Word, Png, Jpg, Bmp)? Does Acumatica provide any API to do this or maybe somebody know any free libraries which can help me with this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607669/how-do-i-convert-word-files-to-pdf-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You do it like you would do in any other C# program.

Some API suggestion:

- For Excel/Word use Microsoft Office Interop API
- For PNG, JPG, BMP use Microsoft .Net Framework

File management in Acumatica is different though so you can use the following example as a starting point to convert images with Acumatica using the .Net Framework:

```
using PX.SM;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;

// Create file maintenance graph to load and save file
UploadFileMaintenance fileGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<UploadFileMaintenance>();

// Files are attached to DAC records NoteID fields, get UID (unique identifier) of files
Guid[] uids = PXNoteAttribute.GetFileNotes(Base.Caches[typeof(DAC)], dacRecord);

if (uids.Length > 0)
{
    // Get first file attached to DAC record using UID
    // Note that FileInfo is part of Acumatica PX.SM namespace and is not .Net FileInfo class
    FileInfo fileInfo = fileGraph.GetFile(uids[0]);

    if (fileInfo != null)
    {  
       // Converting file raw binary data to a .Net Image object
       Image image = ProcessImage(fileInfo.BinData);

       // Write converted image to new file.
       // File extension is changed but actual image conversion 
       // happens in ConvertImageToByteArray function
       const string numberGuidFormat = "N";
       const string imageExtension = ".png";
       FileInfo newImage = new FileInfo(System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(numberGuidFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), imageExtension),
                                        null,
                                        ConvertImageToByteArray(image));

       // Save image file in Acumatica                                      
      fileGraph.SaveFile(newImage, FileExistsAction.ThrowException);

      // Attach image file UID to a DAC record note Eield
      PXNoteAttribute.SetFileNotes(Base.Caches[typeof(DAC)], dacRecord, newImage.UID.Value);
    }    
}

public static System.Drawing.Image ProcessImage(byte[] imageData)
{
    Bitmap convertedImage = null;

    try
    {
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(imageData))
        {
            Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
            convertedImage = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);
            convertedImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

            // Stripping out transparency                               
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(convertedImage);
            graphics.Clear(Color.White);
            graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(image, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // Not a valid image
    }

    return convertedImage;
}


public static byte[] ConvertImageToByteArray(Image image)
{
    using (System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        // Setting the target format here, I used PNG but you can change it to BMP or JPG
        image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```