# Convert word document in to pdf at run time (at the time of uploading)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, ms-word, converters

I have a scenario in my application in which user can `upload business case document` which is word document, and other users(admin and super admin) can see that business case and approve the document.

What is happening is `admins and super admins have to download` `word document` , which i don't want , i want them to see that document in a `pdf format`.

I could do that by restricting the user to upload only pdf files but that is not i want , I want him to upload word document and at the time of saving that file in to server , i want to save as `PDF formtat` .

Current code is working fine but it is saving file as word file , i want to save the file as pdf format.

```
int count = 0;
                foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in emailasign.Files)
                {

                    var filename = "";
                    //Checking file is available to save.  
                    if (file != null)
                    {
                        var random = new Random();
                        filename = random.Next(111111, 999999).ToString() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                        var ServerSavePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/") + filename);
                        //Save file to server folder  
                        file.SaveAs(ServerSavePath);
                        count++;
                    }
                    if (count > 1)
                    {
                        TempData["OrignalFile"] += "," + file.FileName;
                        TempData["FileName"] += "," + filename;
                    }
                    else if (count == 1)
                    {
                        TempData["OrignalFile"] = file.FileName;
                        TempData["FileName"] = filename;
                    }
                }
```

Note: Right now it is accepting all format but i will restrict it in to word document only , so at the the time of uploading the document , i want to convert it in to PDF format and than save it on server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert Word files to PDF programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607669/how-do-i-convert-word-files-to-pdf-programmatically)

Comment: Why is a PDF file important? Are the admins viewing in a browser? If the admins want to view the document in a browser, why not view the Word document?