# Converting WORD doc to PDF after using as template into Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application() in c# win form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ado.net

**This is a special case. I have used word doc as a template into Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application()  and I used it in my application at the end of all operations I want to convert this used document doc to PDF. I have to convert "document" doc whom I have shown in given code into PDF. This is very important for me please help me. Thanks **

```
 var application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
var document = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
 document = application.Documents.Add(Template: ConnectDb.filepath);
```

Comment: [This might helpful. Check with it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607669/how-do-i-convert-word-files-to-pdf-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool name "Spire" that convert your Word to PDF.

You can install it as a NuGet package.

[Spire Website](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/free-doc-component.html#.XJIZXyj7SM9)

[Example of Converting Word to PDF using Spire](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Knowledgebase/Spire.Doc/Program-Guide/How-to-Convert-Word-to-PDF.html)

Comment: Dear Sir i already know this we use string path to convert . Problem is this we are using that string in  Given below

Comment: document = application.Documents.Add(Template: ConnectDb.filepath);

Comment: In the above line of code and now this document doesn't have only string. It hold whole template inside . so when i use "document" to use for covvetring gives me error . i need your help pls