# .NET Core PDF and RTF document generation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, pdfsharp, migradoc

Looking for suggestions for libraries that can generate PDF and RTF documents from stored data (not "HTML to PDF" or "URL to PDF"). With all functionality for adding images, encryption etc. We are currently looking for an alternative to **PDFSharp-MigraDoc-GDI**, which, although works with .NET Core, does not fully support it and we see compiler warnings - **"This package may not be compatible with your project"**. We have also been getting issues on the IIS tier regarding GDI+. We've decided to play it safe and find an alternative. Does anyone have a solution that they would recommend? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can write whole new documents using the Microsoft.Office.Interop library, here is this post that's talk about it (be careful about deploying things like these, you might need an office instalation running on the server):

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/muralidharan.d/how-to-create-word-document-using-C-Sharp/

And I've found this post about using the library to print PDFs:

[How do I convert Word files to PDF programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607669/how-do-i-convert-word-files-to-pdf-programmatically)

It's not much but hope that it helps, regards!