# ASP.NET creating OpenXML Word Documents - Convert to pdf?

Tags: asp.net, pdf

I've got an ASP.NET application creating Word Documents using openxml.
Is there a free solution to convert the docx/openxml output to PDF on the webserver? Note - I'm not using Word or the Word interop!

Comment: Have you had a look at the following thread on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607669/how-do-i-convert-word-files-to-pdf-programmatically

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159744/converting-ms-word-documents-to-pdf-in-asp-net

Comment: I've checked out a fair bit on here and most seems to be for Word Automation (which isn't recommended for server side) or paid components. I'm hoping there is something free available